# Framer support via Instant NPM and ESM

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, framerjs

How best to use MUI components in Framer these days?

The last time I used MUI, there was a Framer folder in the code and I did an NPM install to access the Framer examples. This was possible via the old Framer Desktop App.

But the new version of Framer has 2 new options:

1. **Instant NPM** (Beta) https://www.framer.com/sites/npm/ and
2. **ESM modules** https://www.framer.com/docs/guides/using-external-code/

How best to not only access the Framer examples but to edit them and create my own too.

Comment: I also want to know this question. I'm trying to move the storybook component to Framer.